# Does changing the resolution in Display Setting work correctly with Nvidia Server Settings

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

I want to know since in 11.04 it did not work, if after upgrading to 11.10 will the resolutions in display settings when change will actually change the resolution. I ask this since when using my Nvidia car I could only change the resolution from the Nvidia X Server Settings and not the Display Settings. Would be nice to know that I can change them from the Display Settings also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It works now. You can even find the option in an easier way:

[image]

You will also notice that the Display Settings does not show all resolutions that Nvidia Settings provides. This is because Display Settings takes into account the Display Hardware you are using (LCD, LED, TV, Monitor) and Nvidia Settings just shows all available resolutions for your video card.